# Upload a file using javascript in a drag drop webpage

Tags: javascript

I have an internal work webpage that supports drag and drop. I am required to upload 10 files from the network drive to this page. I am trying to automate this using javascript so instead of manually dragging the files from the 10 different folders to this website I can use script.

The drag API doesn't seem to let me do that. Where do i get started?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/Drag_operations#drop

Comment: Might just go with an existing library. Something like dropzone is mature and debugged. https://www.dropzonejs.com/

Comment: dadash to too cafe bazaari? ( pak mikonam ino badan)